# Getting a Jupyter notebook to listen to input events while running a continuous process?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to do something in a Jupyter notebook that runs a continuous process, but with a pause button to interrupt it. Below is a simplified version of what I've done so far, but it seems Ipython wants to complete the entire `run()` function before it executes commands it receives from the button. The problem, of course, being that `run()` will never finish unless interrupted.

Interestingly, the below strategy works just fine in my Tkinter frontend so long as I put a `pause(0.0001)` at the end of the `updateGraph()` function. Architecturally, I'd be curious why Tkinter is willing to listen to input events during that pause but Jupyter isn't. But more importantly, is there a way to get Jupyter to listen while running `run()`?

```
from ipywidgets import Button
from IPython.display import display

startstop = Button(description='Run')
startstop.click = run
display(startstop)

def run(b=None):
   running=True
   while running:
      #Do stuff and update display
      updateGraph()
   startstop.click = pause
   startstop.description = 'Pause'

def pause(b=None):
   running = False
   startstop.click = run
   startstop.description = 'Run'
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using [Keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) for this purpose. It is a much simpler approach to the same problem...

```py
import keyboard

def run():
    running=True
    while running:
        pass # some code here...
        if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
            break

run()
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key anytime to stop the execution of the program.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work in a jupyter notebook. Do you have any insights?